# Recording date stamps to the Reminder Time and Date Released columns?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe

[image]

Is there a way to record a given date to these columns? I looked all over the place for a way to do it with PowerShell or a cli program sadly I found nothing for these two columns. I was only able to find solutions for  Date Created and Date Modified.

I would appreciate it if someone who knows more about this shares some insight.

Thanks.

Comment: the released date is for objects that have a release date ... such as music, video, or books. the reminder date is for items that have such an attribute ... like meetings or tasks. you are showing file or dir objects ... and they DO NOT have such attributes.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey. I see, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]